# BFS for shortest path in weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was revising single source shortest path algorithms and it was mentioned that BFS would not work properly .
but , shouldnt it work properly if the algorithm was dijkstra like ( using dist[node] instead of visit[node])? , I also had problems determining the complexity of this algorithm

Comment: Sorry, what? What do you mean by "using dist[node] instead of visit[node]" - you can't arbitrarily replace a boolean with a number in an algorithm without making other changes. Dijkstra's is a generalisation of BFS. BFS doesn't work on general graphs (with non-negative edge weights) because it ignores edge weights.

Comment: you ever code dijkstra? it used distance instead of bool , well u can use an  if like when (dist[now]+edge weight < dist[adj[now]] ) then u insert in on the queue . of course its what I meant dijkstra like. sorry .

Comment: If you're still doing BFS without considering edge weights in visiting order, you'd be visiting nodes in the wrong order, so you either need to revisit a lot of nodes in the worst case (making it take, I think, exponential time) or the answer would be wrong. If you do consider edge weights in visiting order, that's just Dijkstra's.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work properly. The defining properties of BFS and Dijkstra's algorithm are the order of "exploring" new nodes.

In BFS, you discover nodes based on their unweighted distance from the source.

This results in failures to find shortest paths after you 'update' some previously explored node. Example:

```
v1--1-->v2--1-->v3--1-->v4--1-->v5--1-->v6
|                               ^
V                               |
--------------100---------------
```

In BFS, even with your solution, the order of discovery and updating of costs is:

```
v1:0
v2:1
v5:100
v3:2
v6:101
v4:3
v5:(update): 5
```

But note that now, v6 is does not have its correct value.

If you want to tweak this solution more and make every 'update' trigger rexploring all neighbors - this will cost significantly more to explore (since you are not bounded by `|V|+|E|` anymore, and in fact can result in very inefficient algorithm.